# se editan todos los elementos de una lista al solo editar uno C#

Tags: c#

tengo un problema quiero crear una lista de objetos, primero tomo un objeto como  base, relleno la lista con ese objeto luego cada uno sera editado con valores random pero al editar uno edita tanto la lista como el objeto base como evito eso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En lugar de poner el codigo como imagen, ayudaria que sea el texto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aki esta mi respuesta, espero que te sirve te puse un ejemplo ke puedes comprobar

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Puedes ir cambiando esta linea por cualkiera de los nombres
            // de las funciones creadas aki abajo para que veas el resultado
            // Las que deben servirte como respuestas son Copia2 y Copia3
            Copia3();
        }

        //Comportamiento que explicastes con esta función puedes ver como sucede tal y como lo experimentastes
        static void Copia1()
        {
            Person me = new Person { Name = "Dariel", Age = 28 };
            List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                list.Add(me);
            }
            list[0].Name = "Dariel Ramos";
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre del primero: " + list[0].Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre del segundo: " + list[1].Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre del original: " + me.Name);
        }

        // Comportamiento esperado como respuesta a tu pregunta puedes modificar tantos elementos
        // quieras de tu lista que no se vera afectado ni el original, ni ninguno de ellos excepto
        // el que acabas de modificar
        static void Copia2()
        {
            Person me = new Person { Name = "Dariel", Age = 28 };
            List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                // Llamo a una función que cree dentro de mi clase Person para devolver una
                // copia de los datos del objeto original, asi cuando lo modifique no se cambia
                // por referencia
                list.Add(me.Copy());
            }
            list[0].Name = "Dariel Ramos";
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre del primero: " + list[0].Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre del segundo: " + list[1].Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre del original: " + me.Name);
        }


        // Comportamiento esperado como respuesta a tu pregunta puedes modificar tantos elementos
        // quieras de tu lista que no se vera afectado ni el original, ni ninguno de ellos excepto
        // el que acabas de modificar
        static void Copia3()
        {
            Person me = new Person { Name = "Dariel", Age = 28 };
            List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                // Llamo a la función Clone para devolver una
                // copia de los datos del objeto original necesitar hacer el casting (Person)
                // pk esa función devuelve un object y tu necesitas agregar a tu lista
                // un objeto de tipo Person, logrando asi cuando lo modifique no se cambia por referencia
                list.Add((Person)me.Clone());
            }
            list[0].Name = "Dariel Ramos";
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre del primero: " + list[0].Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre del segundo: " + list[1].Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre del original: " + me.Name);
        }
    }

    // Clase Persona usada en el ejemplo
    // Si vas a usar la función 2 puedes remover el : ICloneable
    class Person: ICloneable
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public int Age
        {
            get; set;
        }

        // Si usas la función Copia2 como respuesta dejas esta función
        // puedes eliminar la de abajo (Clone)
        public Person Copy()
        {
            return new Person { Name = this.Name, Age = this.Age };
        }

        // Si usas la función Copia3 como respuesta dejas esta función
        // puedes eliminar la de arriba (Copy)
        public object Clone()
        {
            return this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Debes recordar que las `instancia` de `objetos` se acceden por `referencia` con lo cual si asignas varias variables a esa misma instancia todas apuntan a la `misma direccion en memoria`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deberias `clonar` el objeto para que la `instancia` y el `puntero a memoria` sean diferentes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Cloning Objects In .NET Framework](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cloning-objects-in-net-framework/)

La idea es que la clase que tienes la implementes la interface `ICloneable`

```
class NombreClass : ICloneable
{
    //propiedades

    public object Clone()
    {
        return new NombreClass(){
           //asignar propiedades a la nueva instancia
        };
    }

}
```

Pero existen otras tecnicas si el objeto es complejo como seria serializarlo y deserializarlo